# Median of multiple vectors of double (c++, vector < vector<double> >)

Tags: c++, vector, double, median

I have a datastructure containing a vector of vectors which each consist of about ~16000000 double values.

I now want to median-combine these vectors, meaning, of each original vectors I take the values at place i, calculate the median of these and then store them in the resulting vector at place i.

I already have the straight-forward solution, but it is incredible slow:

```
vector< vector<double> > vectors; //vectors contains the datavectors
vector<double> tmp;
vector<double> result;
vector<double> tmpmedian;
double pixels = 0.0;
double matrixcount = vectors.size();

    tmp = vectors.at(0);
    pixels = tmp.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < pixels; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < matrixcount; j++) {
            tmp = vectors.at(j);
            tmpmedian.push_back(tmp.at(i));
        }
        result.push_back(medianOfVector(tmpmedian));
        tmpmedian.clear();
    }

return result;
```

And medianOfVector looks like this:

```
double result = 0;

if ((vec.size() % 2) != 0) {
    vector<double>::iterator i = vec.begin();
    vector<double>::size_type m = (vec.size() / 2);

    nth_element(i, i + m, vec.end());
    result = vec.at(m);
} else {
    vector<double>::iterator i = vec.begin();
    vector<double>::size_type m = (vec.size() / 2) - 1;

    nth_element(i, i + m, vec.end());
    result = (vec.at(m) + vec.at(m + 1)) / 2;
}

return result;
```

I there an algorithm or a way to do this faster, it takes nearly an eternity to do it.

---

Edit: Thank you for your replies, in case anyone is interested here is the fixed version, it now takes about 9sec to median combine three vectors with ~16000000 elements, mean combining takes around 3sec:

```
vector< vector<double> > vectors; //vectors contains the datavectors
vector<double> *tmp;
vector<double> result;
vector<double> tmpmedian;

    tmp = &vectors.at(0);
    int size = tmp->size();
    int vectorsize = vectors.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < vectorsize; j++) {
            tmp = &vectors.at(j);
            tmpmedian.push_back(tmp->at(i));
        }
        result.push_back(medianOfVector(tmpmedian));
        tmpmedian.clear();
    }
return result;
```

And medianOfVector:

```
double result = 0;

if ((vec.size() % 2) != 0) {
    vector<double>::iterator i = vec.begin();
    vector<double>::size_type m = (vec.size() / 2);

    nth_element(i, i + m, vec.end());
    result = vec.at(m);
} else {
    vector<double>::iterator i = vec.begin();
    vector<double>::size_type m = (int) (((vec.size() - 1) / 2));
    nth_element(i, i + m, vec.end());
    double min = vec.at(m);
    double max = *min_element(i + m + 1, vec.end());
    result = (min + max) / 2;
}

return result;
}
```

Comment: I am not sure how many useful algorithmic suggestions people will be able to make without any more information about the data being processed. Are their any further assumptions that can be made about the data, or properties you know it will have?


If you are dealing with lots of variable length vectors of unknown contents there might not be much you can do algorithmically (but maybe still some improvement through implementation).

Comment: Seems to me like this could be done in parallel? Have you considered offloading this to the GPU (using CUDA/C++AMP/OpenCL...)?

Comment: You are making a lot of copies of vectors. Are you able to pass around pointers to the original vectors?

Comment: In your medianOfVector, you call nth_element to set the mth element but then access the (m+1)th as well.  This is not necessarily set, unfortunately.

Comment: @Owen: It's sadly kind of random, the data is a representation of images, with a size >16 MPixels.

Comment: @Borgleader: Considered I have it, but I think this would be too much and complicated for my current level of experience.

Comment: @NeilKirk: Ahh, thanks! Changed it to pointers instead of vectors, it is so much faster now, I didn't know that using references would cause a deep copy.

Comment: @GuyGreer: Thanks, I'll change it, but it seems that I have to call nth_element twice, once for m and then for m+1.

Comment: You are not using references.

Comment: @user3199134 You could call `min_element(i+m+1, vec.end())` to just find the smallest element to the right of the mth, since `nth_element` has the side effect that all elements before m will be smaller than all the ones the right.  This will run faster than a second call to `nth_element`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A couple of points, both stemming from the fact that you've defined `tmp` as a vector instead of (for example) a reference.

```
vector<double> tmp;

tmp = vectors.at(0);
pixels = tmp.size();
```

Here you're copying the entirety of `vectors[0]` into `tmp` just to extract the size. You'll almost certainly gain some speed by avoiding the copy:

```
pixels = vectors.at(0).size();
```

Instead of copying the entire vector just to get its size, this just gets a *reference* to the first vector, and gets the size of that existing vector.

```
for (int i = 0; i < pixels; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < matrixcount; j++) {
        tmp = vectors.at(j);
        tmpmedian.push_back(tmp.at(i));
    }
```

Here you're again copying the entirety of `vectors.at(j)` into `tmp`. But (again) you don't really need a new copy of all the data--you're just retrieving a single item from that copy. You can retrieve the data you need directly from the original vector without copying the whole thing:

```
tmpmedian.push_back(vectors.at(j).at(i));
```

A possible next step would be to switch from using `.at` to `operator[]`:

```
tmpmedian.push_back(vectors[j][i]);
```

This is much more of a tradeoff though--it's not likely to gain nearly as much, and loses a bit of safety (range checking) in the process. To avoid losing safety, you could consider (for example) using range-based `for` loops instead of the counted `for` loops in your current code.

Along rather different lines, you could instead change from using a `vector<vector<double>>` to using a small wrapper around a vector to give 2D addressing into a single vector. Using this with a suitable column-wise iterator, you could avoid creating `tmpmedian` as basically a copy of a column of the original 2D matrix--instead, you'd pass a column-wise iterator to `medianOfVector`, and just iterate through a column of the original data in-place.